# Working with JDateChooser and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jdatechooser

I need a help. I am doing a reservation system and my doubt is:

I have 2 `JDateChoosers` and `JTextFields` and one `JDateChooser` is for the start and one is for the end.

For example the user selects a date from the start `JDateChooser` and after he entered the number of years in the `JTextField` automatically the end `JDateChooser` changes the year. The user can't edit the end `JDateChooser`.

1. Select the Date from `JDateChooser` "start".
2. Enter the number of years in the `JTextField`.
3. Automatically the "end" `JDateChooser`'s value changes.

Comment: Can you post your code? There's no real question here, just what you want to do. What is the *specific* issue you are facing? Compiler error? Unexpected output(s)? Have you read the documentation on Date in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [the mediator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

Basically you will have one object (the mediatory) which will be responsible for coordinating the state between a number of GUI components.  So, when one person enters in something in one of the text boxes, that mediator is a listener on the text box, and will set the other GUI component's state accordingly.